# SSIS row count give unexpected results

Tags: ssis

I am dynamically loading few sets (7) of flat file(.txt) located in diffrent path, but on the same server, by using espression to set the connection string for the flatfiles.

Each file is loaded and pass through row count transformation in Dataflowtask in an ssis package to give the rowcounts. But the counts which is received from the rowcount transformation is not the expected count, mainly getting half of the actual counts or 1/3 of the actual count for most of the files.

Example

```
filename        rowcounts            actualcount
file1            15000                 30000
file2            10000                 10000
file3            18000                 54000
```

Comment: are you retrieving the row count in the same data flow the rowcount transformation is?

Comment: yes Jayvee... i am using one data flow task.. but it seems the flatfile source connectionmanager is taking only one format to refrence the files.. but the files are basically of different format(mainly differing in number of columns not in type) all are text file only..

Comment: the result of the row count can't be used in the same data flow as it gets updated at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I was dealing with a CSV file being read in the same way.
Exactly half the records were not present. The root cause for me was a Text Qualifier being set incorrectly in the flat file connection manager.